# Workarounds for Selenium not clicking button with InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I've got a button on a webpage that Webdriver will not click when I'm running via IE - I've tried the below workarounds but no luck -

Clicking via Javascript:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$(arguments[0]).click()", webElement)
```

Using SendKeys:

```
webElement.SendKeys(keys.Enter)
```

Using the Action Builder

```
Actions test = new Actions(driver);
        test.moveToElement(webElement);
        test.clickAndHold();
        test.release();
        test.build();
        test.perform();
```

Making sure the window is the active one, then clicking on the parent object, then the object itself

Problem is, none of them work. I've checked in Firefox and Chrome and the script runs fine. I've confirmed that the element is being found when using IE. Are there any other workarounds I can try?

Comment: Do you have a example page where this problem is reproduced? It might be worth it to file this as a bug if it's working properly with the other drivers.

Comment: Unfortunately can only reproduce on an internal app. Have managed to solve the issue by switching window focus, forcing scrolling, clicking the parent element, clicking the element and then sending Javascript. Obviously overkill somewhere in there, but just happy it's working.

Comment: I believe that the IE window needs to be topmost and in focus for a lot actions to work properly. At least that was my experience with it.

Comment: What's the WebDriver version that you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Seems you are tyring to use JQuery style click... normal javascript style click should work.

Try this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement)
```

I always found successful with the following for clicking an element in IE.

1. If is a checkbox/radio: `webElement.click();`
2. Clickable input element: `webElement.sendKeys("\n");`
3. For other elements, use the above said JS style click.

Comment: I would hug you if I could!

Answer (score 1):

If the button is a form submit button, you can use : `webElement.submit()` on another field of the form.