# Unable to click() or submit() input using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

So I have an input element on a page and I need to click on it to go to another page. Problem is that when I user click() or submit() on the element nothing happens. I have a custom highlight method that is working so I can see that I am actually on the correct element. The click() just seems to not be working on it for some unknown reason.

Here is the html I'm working with

```
<TBODY>
<TR style="" class=" STDLISTROW_O" onmouseover=listMouseOver(this);  onmouseout=listMouseOut(this); saveBG>
<TD class=STDLISTBTN>
<INPUT style="COLOR: " onmouseover="listBtnMouseOver(this);   window.status = this.status_txt;" onmouseout="listBtnMouseOut(this); window.status = '';" onclick=" event.cancelBubble = true;  if (this.getAttribute('clicked') == 'false')  { document.location.href = 'client$.startup?P_CLIENT_ID=7605677'; this.setAttribute('clicked', 'true'); } " value=ECR type=button status_txt="client$.startup?P_CLIENT_ID=7605677" clicked="false" saveBtnBG saveBtnC></TD>
```

Here is my Selenium/Java method

```
public void clickECRButtonWithID(String clientID) {
    log.info("Click the ECR button for the row with client id: " + clientID);
    WebElement idRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'"
            + clientID + "')]/ancestor::tr"));
    WebElementExtender.highlightElement(idRow);
    WebElement ecrButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='ECR']"));
    WebElementExtender.highlightElement(ecrButton);
    ecrButton.click();
}
```

I have also tried isolating the parent td of the input and clicking on it with no luck. I'm at a loss here.

- I need to add that I am using Internet Explorer Driver (IEDriverServer) and am on IE9 browser. Unfortunately that's all this application will run on!

Comment: The fact that the input does not have a 'type' attribute has something to do with it. Does it work if the input has  the attribute type='button' ?

Comment: @SteveCrawford It does have the attribute type='button'. Look at the very end past all the javascript.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I missed it since it doesn't have quotes around it. I'm not 100% but this doesn't seem to be valid html, what are 'saveBtnBG' and  'saveBtnC', should they be classes?

Comment: @SteveCrawford I'm sure it's not valid html. The application is a mess and I have no access to change anything or ad IDs to any element. It's a challenge for sure!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First try other browsers like Firefox and Chrome to make sure your code (locator and such) is correct. Then a couple solutions you might want to try on IE.

- Focus on the element before clicking.

```java
ecrButton.click(); // dummy click to focus
// or ecrButton.sendKeys("\n"); // also tries to focus
ecrButton.click(); // do your actual click
```

- Use click method from `Actions` class.

```java
new Actions(driver).click(ecrButton).perform();
```

- Inject JavaScript clicking

```java
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ecrButton);
```

Comment: You must have answered right before me. I am marking yours as the correct answer since it contains the javascript technique that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879115/workarounds-for-selenium-not-clicking-button-with-internetexplorerdriver) question and it contained the answer that worked for me.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", ecrButton);
```

There seems to be some sort of bug in the IEDriverServer that doesn't allow you to click on some inputs. Using javascript instead seems to work well.

*Much appreciation to @KrishPrabakar